# Full list of AngularJS directives?

Tags: angularjs

I'm learning AngularJS. Is there a good comprehensive list of all the out-of-the-box directives? The [FAQ](http://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq) mentions `ng-repeat`, `ng-show`, and `ng-class`, but I get the sense there are plenty more.  It seems odd I can't find a single place to discover the rest.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The listing can be found on their API page:

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/

If you're new to AngularJS, you might find this useful as well:

http://www.cheatography.com/proloser/cheat-sheets/angularjs/

It goes over the directives, filters, etc. and provides snippets of useful information on everything. You may need to read up more on something in the docs if it's confusing, but generally I find that cheat sheet to be enough for simple tasks.

Comment: That cheat sheet is awesome! Thanks :)

Comment: The following is also awesome, rich reading for those starting with angular: http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/10/more-angularjs-magic-to-supercharge-your-webapp.html

Comment: http://www.techstrikers.com/AngularJS/angularjs-built-in-directives.php this may also helpfull