# Is there a list of Angular directives sorted by frequency of use?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'd like to know how often various directives are used.  Could make it useful for knowing what to study harder than other things.

Comment: Duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14350412/full-list-of-angularjs-directives

Comment: edited.  Full list is different than list with frequency of use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a comment on question but it was too long so i post this as an answer.

First, frequency is a vague term, what type of frequency are you looking for? How many times the directive appears on code or how many files it appears on? `ng-controller` for instance by appearance-in-code count should fall far behind `ng-model` but `ng-controller` is almost always used in every template.(Though this also depends on the structure of the project a lot.)

I don't think there would be a definitive list either way. I assume directives like `ng-model`, and `ng-repeat` appear a lot more than the others in code. `ng-model` being the main functioning point of angularjs and `ng-repeat` for frequent need of using arrays of information. Some people may never use `ng-change` and always use `$watch`(not a directive) others may use it alot. Directive frequency all depends on the project.

And I also think this is not what you should focus on while you are studying angular. Directives are only one of the many parts of angular. And frequency of use does not imply importance or complexity. What you should be focusing on is so called angular-way of doing things and philosophy behind it.

All directives are documented and there is plenty of answers here in SO for many of the questions you might have. Best way to learn is to start building a project, and when you need to do something that you think can be done with directives check the docs, if you can't find anything there try to write your own. Scope,custom directives,linking, how angular digest loop works etc. is what you should study more.